# How to clean a database and read it right in the R

Tags: r, dataframe, awk

When downloading the database of daily values and tickets of 2019 from the transparency portal at the link [http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/viagens][1], I verified that it has errors in the column separator. Some lines have more ";" than others. How can I check the terminal when compiling:

```
cat 2019_Viagem.csv | awk -F ";" '{print NF-1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

How to remove all lines with more than 15 separators and save the new database in format `.csv` for statistical analysis?

Here is my initial code:

```
    library("tidyverse")
    library("readr")
    library("data.table")
    library("stringr")
    library("lubridate")
    #unzip("2019_20190630_Viagens.zip")
    options(datatable.fread.input.cmd.message=FALSE)
    Diaria2019_Via <- "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 2019_Viagem.csv"
    Diaria2019 <- data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via,dec = ",")


    Warning messages:
    1: In data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",") :
      Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
    2: In data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",") :
      Stopped early on line 7378. Expected 16 fields but found 18. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<"0000000000015769552";"Realizada";"53000";"Ministério do Desenvolvimento Regional";"53000";"Ministério do Desenvolvimento Regional - Unidades com vínculo direto";"***.043.57*-**";"ARMIN AUGUSTO BRAUN";"";"20190115";"20190116";"São Paulo/SP";"Representar a Secretaria Nacional de Proteção e Defesa Civil - SEDEC, no Seminário "Proteção e Defesa Civil Aplicada", onde Ministrará palestra sobre "Apoio Federal na Resposta a Desastres"; participará reunião com pessoal do Hospital Albert Eins>>
```

The above message suggests using `quote =" "` and `fill = NULL`, however, none of them work. The code below incorrectly reads the Daily Value column. I was unable to transform the data structure of this column into numeric values.

```
Diaria_2019 <- read_delim("2019_Viagem.csv", 
                          ";", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ".",encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), 
                          trim_ws = TRUE)
```

A possible start to remove lines with more than 15 separators of type `;` was the code below, but also did not work!

```
teste <- readLines("2019_Viagem.csv")
count <- str_count(teste, ';')
teste <- teste[count==15]
write.csv2(teste,"plan2019.csv",row.names = FALSE)
Diaria2019_Via <- "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 plan2019.csv"
Diaria2019 <- data.table::fread(Diaria2019_Via, dec = ",")
```

Comment: What does this have to do with awk ? Either explain what help you need with your awk script with show sample input and expected output or remove the awk tag.

Answer (score 1):

Read the input with 'readLines', apply a regular expression to each line to count the separators, delete the lines that have more than 15 separators, and then read the cleansed input with 'read_delim'.

Comment: I added a code to your suggestion, however, I still can not solve it!